# Embed terminal on desktop in Gnome 3.4

Tags: command-line, gnome

I'm wondering if it is possible to embed the terminal on the desktop under GNOME 3. 4. I would like it to be fully transparent, without any borders or shadows, basically to display just the text, even without the menu! Now before I get a comment to search the forums for an answer, I would like to add:

- The screenlet terminal does not work for me and is not what I want
- I do not use CCSM, don't even know if it is possible under GNOME 3
- Devilspie does not work (it makes all my menus and borders from all my windows dissapear, and yes I followed instructions on how to make it happen

So  before saying to me that I should use the search function,  think about what I am asking.
My biggest problem is that all options that I tried do not work under GNOME 3.
So if anyone knows for a solution, or explanation as to why not-

Comment: Did you try the guake terminal?

Comment: hey! thx for the reply, but quake is not actually what I hope to achieve. I was hoping more that the terminal be a permanent part of wallpaper.

Comment: [Embedded Terminal on Gnome 3 Desktop](http://raerav.com/embedded-terminal-on-gnome-3-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, i remember way back when, i wanted to do this very thing, i did a quick Google search and remembered that i used DevilsPie back in the Gnome 2.x days, however, according to the GNOME wiki, DP is now unmaintained, but DevilsPie2 is now around.

Bear in mind i have not tried this for years, but according to the DP2 website (http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/) its simply a matter of creating a .lua script in /home/yourusername/.config/devilspie2/ and putting a few rules into that file, such as window placement, position, name and such. See the "simple script example" in the git README for an explanation: https://raw.github.com/gusnan/devilspie2/master/README

Also, make sure to use the devilspie2 package, NOT the devilspie package, they are not the same thing, the latter is the older version that im guessing will not work with Gnome 3.